# How to capture output from docker build to a file?

Tags: docker

I am using docker buildkit to build an image, which produces a lot of output from the command in the docker file.  Something is going wrong in the build, and there is a lot of text to scroll through on the terminal.  I would like to capture it to a file, where I can search it with my text editor.  However, it appears that docker writes the output directly to the terminal, not going through stdout or stderr.

That is:

```
$ docker build . <various args> 2>&1 > build.log
```

still produces output to the terminal, and build.log is empty.

I found a page suggesting `--progress=plain`, but that only appears to affect what is output, not where it is output.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me :

```
docker build -t nice-image . > bla.log
```

using `Docker version 20.10.7, build v20.10.7` and zsh shell.

Comment: Is there something similar for ```docker run <container_id>```?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this and found an answer over in the [Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/capture-ouput-of-docker-build-into-a-log-file/123178). In short, the output is not written to the standard output stream (stdout) but to the standard error stream (stderr). This worked for me:

```bash
# write everything to build.log
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain  . &> build.log
```

Other things to try are:

```bash
# only write error output to build.log
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain  . 2> build.log

# stream output to console and write it to build.log
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain . 2>&1 | tee build.log
```